# Dynamic SQL Within A Stored Procedure Security

Tags: sql, security

I've got the SQL stored procedure from hell that I've created and all input parameters are parameterised for security but it's not running as quick as I'd like so I wanted to make it dynamic and so a bit more efficient.

I know I can keep my input parameters to my stored procedure, then within it create a dynamic SQL statement into which I can then pass the input parameters of the stored procedure, but are there any security implications I need to be aware of when doing this?  I'm guessing not as it just another set of parameters and they should be treated the same as the parameters passed to the current stored procedure.

Obviously, producing code like this "WHERE OrderNo = ' + @orderno is asking for trouble - I will be doing 'WHERE OrderNo = @orderno' in the dynamic SQL, but is there anything else I need to be aware of?
Thx MH

PS - before anyone suggests it, I can't create the SQL dynamically at the client side using LINQ or similar - it all (for various reasons) has to be contained and controlled at the database level

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?, Do you have sample code of what you are trying to do? And your text lacks a bit of whitespace which does not invite reading.

Comment: Why do you think making the contents of a dynamically built SQL string will improve performance?

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor - Presumably because the OP can dynamically leave out irrelevant bits that relate to optional parameters. `@`Mad If this is the case and you are on SQL Server see [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: I'm on SQL server 2008 - it's a massively complex SQL statement (about 2 pages of SQL - I have to deal with some horrendously complex data) with lots of conditionals and I've tested the speed increase by removing various parts of the query and re-running it to simulate different conditions. There are 2 or 3 very different queries that all exhibit this behaviour, so I was after a general theory rather than an application to a specific query

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor it is, indeed, as Martin Smith says, there are a bunch of options and whole code sections that are dependent on various conditions, but these slow the query down when not needed to the point that I think the overhead of optimsing the query on-the-fly will be less than running the extra code.  The data is hellish and all over the place so the query, unfortunately, can't be simplified, and it's live so I can't batch post, sorting it out, and then report on that

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor thanks, that might be very useful - I'm doing the static method at the moment but that OPTION(RECOMPILE) might be what I needed to sort out the speed issues.

Comment: @Martin Smith Aha, OPTION(RECOMPILE) worked wonders, thanks - it changed a 20-odd second search to a 2-3 second search and it means I don't have to use dynamic SQL, either.  I think I can also tweak this and get this down a bit more, too, but that's the killer time-saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a form of SQL injection that many people don't think about when doing dynamic SQL in stored procedures: **SQL Truncation attacks**.

With a SQL truncation attack, the attacker injects a long peace of text making the used text variable overflow and lose part of the query.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163523.aspx) gives more information about this.

Comment: I have a great quote on the difference between `loose` and `lose`, but it will not pass the censorship at SO :-)/:-(, anyway +1

Comment: I define and limit the lengths of all input parameters, so that should be ok, but is there a limit to the dynamice SQL code length?

Comment: @Mad: That length is determined by the variable you use. For instance: `DECLARE @QUERY AS VARCHAR(1000)`. That query will get truncated after 1000 characters. You can easily solve this problem in MS SQL 2005 and up by using `varchar(max)`.

Comment: I'd guessed that, I just thought I'd better check there wasn't any other limit =8)

Answer (score 0):

Where your parameters are always Data Items, both when being passed to the StoredProc *and* when used in yor DynamicSQL, everything will stay safe.

Should any of your StoredProc's parameters end up being table or field names, and so forming part of the structure of the DynamicSQL itself, you introduce a new risk : That the parameter can be used to inject rogue SQL Code.

- To prevent against such an injection attack you should *always* validate any such parameters.

One example of how to do this would be to use the input parameter as a token, rather than substitute it directly into the DynamicSQL...

```
SET @SQL = @SLQ + CASE targetTable WHEN '1'  THEN 'table1'
                                   WHEN 'tx' THEN 'tableX'
                  END
```

Some people suggest you only need to validate on the client application.  But that means that if someone becomes able to execute you SP's directly, the SP has become a point of attack.  I always prefer to validate both on the client AND in the server.

**EDIT**  Performance

Note that using DynamicSQL isn't always a guarnatee of performance increases.  If you use parameterised queries, the execution plans can indeed be stored.  But if the queries do vary greatly, you may still find a significant overhead in compiling the SQL.

There is also the fact that dependancy tracking is lost.  It's not possible to see what tables the SP is dependant on, because the code is hidden away as strings.

I have very rarely found that DynamicSQL is needed.  Often a complex query can be reformed as several optimised queries.  Or the data can be re-structured to meet the new demands.  Or even a rethink of both the data and the algorithm using the data.  One might even be able to *suggest* that a dependancy on DynamicSQL is an indicator of another underlying problem.

Perhaps it's not in the scope of your question, but it would be interesting to see the actual puzzle you're facing; to see if anyone has any alternative approaches for you.

Comment: Thanks - I don't have table names as parameters and already pass in values for other options as you listed in your optional table code =8)  Unfortunately, the data cannot be simplified - it's from up to 15 tables from up to 5 databases and is live, so there's not a lot I can do from that side - hence the need for the complexity of the SQL.  Another option we've been thinking of is getting the simpler selections and data and then posting that into a temporary table and then performing the more complex (from the data's structure, point of view) searches and selections on that data.